# The forward button doesn't work in my code

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

That view is a web link to a page where you you play music: http://www.goear.com/listen/5681ce5/old-man-river-show-boat-paul-robeson When the phone is locked, the music is playing OK. The play button is OK, but when I push the forward button (when is locked the mobile) something wrong happen and the player is off (and obviusly the button doesn't work)

I mean obviously as I do this programmatically in xcode. I have a web application made with the view. Maybe changing something in the appdelegate?

This is my code:

```
 NSError  * sessionError =  nil ; 
NSError  * activationError =  nil ; 
[[ AVAudioSession sharedInstance ] setCategory :  AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error :& sessionError ]; 
[[ AVAudioSession sharedInstance ] setActive : YES error :  y activationError ];
En el siguiente método:

    -  ( BOOL ) aplicación : ( UIApplication  *) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions de aplicación : ( NSDictionary  *) launchOptions
 { 
    retorno YES ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, First things first the iPhone has four main buttons Home, Lock, Volume Up and Volume Down. So I'm going to assume you mean the next track button on the iPhone media player control center. The one that looks like >>.

With that in mind your webview is playing the music track through a shared AVAudioSession which is what it's suppose to do. When you hit the next track button an event is going to fired to find the next track but since you are using an http stream it will never find one unless you add a listener for that event and make your app receive remote control events.

Otherwise, it's just going to get confused and probably crash or not play anything. More than likely though if you tried it on a device it will start playing a track in your media library.